# Sharing windows 7 id_rsa and id_dsa key to another OS

Tags: ubuntu, git, openssh, rsa, dsa

On my windows 7 I have both id_dsa and id_rsa keys. I've decided that I want to switch to ubuntu 12.04 LTS to be exact. can I transfer my id_dsa and id_rsa keys and other git configurations to Ubuntu? if I did that will I still have the permissions to the repositories I am currently has access to.

note that I've used msysgit to generate my id_dsa and my id_rsa keys.

Comment: oh okay. please move my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's okay to just copy them over: Git for Windows (what you called "msysgit") ships with a build of an OpenSSH client, and since Ubuntu ships OpenSSH as its SSH client as well, the keys require no conversion.

Note that both keys should be placed under the `~/.ssh` directory on the Ubuntu machine (note that if this directory does not yet exist, and you're about to create it by hand, it must be owned by your primary user and group and have `0600` access mode). Then the `id_rsa` file — the private key — must be set to have `0600` access mode. The public key (`id_rsa.pub`) should use `0644` access mode — that is, write access for you only and read access for everyone.

Note that it's okay to lose `id_rsa.pub` as it can be regenerated from your private key at any time.

Comment: do I need the dsa key?

Comment: @user962206, well, that's just *another* key, using a different set of algorythms for cryptography. AFAIK, as long as OpenSSH is concerned, there's no difference, but there's also no point having two keys if you only need one (if you will need another key -- for instance, many SSH guides advise to have one key per client *host),* you will easily generate one (just name it differently from `id_rsa`). See [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/5100) for more info on RSA vs DSA.

Comment: @user962206, one aspect of this might still be not clear, so let me clarify: each key you generate for SSH is distinct, no matter what set of cryptography algorithms is used to handle it. This means each key also has distinct public part and *fingerprint,* and as you might have already noticed, when you make a remote system (Git hosting included) trust your particular key, you use that key's public part. Hence your existing two keys are really distinct -- they're not the same key just using different algos, they are really different.